# FluidMoveBehavior On a StackPanel Flickers Before Animating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

I have a `ItemsControl` With the `FluidMoveBehavior` attached to it like this:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RequirementsSource}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource RequirementTemplateSelector}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <ic:FluidMoveBehavior AppliesTo="Children" Duration="0:0:00.5" Tag="DataContext">
                            <ic:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseX>
                                <BackEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Amplitude="0.5"/>
                            </ic:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseX>
                            <ic:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseY>
                                <BackEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Amplitude="0.5"/>
                            </ic:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseY>
                            </ic:FluidMoveBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

When the items change their sort order they do animate, but first the items sort as if there was no `FluidMoveBehavior` attached and then sort back. That whole thing happens quickly enough that it looks like a flicker before the animation starts.

The `ItemsControl` ItemsSource looks like this:

```
RequirementsSource = new ListCollectionView(Requirements);
ICollectionViewLiveShaping live = (ICollectionViewLiveShaping)RequirementsSource;
live.IsLiveSorting = True;
live.IsLiveFiltering = True;
live.LiveSortingProperties.Add("Rank");
live.LiveFilteringProperties.Add("Owner");
RequirementsSource.SortDescriptions.Add(
    new SortDescription("Rank", ListSortDirection.Ascending)
);
RequirementsSource.Filter = _filterPred;
```

The sort is triggered by the following method:

```
private void SwapRanks(SwapArgs args)
{
    IPropertyRequirement first = args.Warning.Requirements
        .First(r => r.Rank == args.RankToSwap);
    IPropertyRequirement second = args.Warning.Requirements
        .First(r => r.Rank == args.SwapWith);

    int temp = first.Rank;
    first.Rank = second.Rank;
    second.Rank = temp;

    RequirementsSource.Refresh();
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this "flicker" and what I can do to stop it?

Comment: can you give any code to show how you are sorting, as what you have posted looks fine - other than not having the templates to work with

Comment: @Cadogi I have added code that shows the `ItemsSource` Also, the actual code is using templates, I just threw everything in line for the example

Comment: I think declaring: RequirementsSource = New ListCollectionView(Requirements) would refresh the view initialy (by effectively setting a new ItemsSource), then when you are sorting that is what you see using FluidMoveBehavior as it is then moving from what it thinks is the initial position. (I could be way off)

Comment: @Cadogi That code is only in the constructor for the viewmodel. It is not called every time the code is sorted. I added the method that causes the sort to trigger to the question.

Comment: That makes much more sense now. It may be worth holding back the refresh of your data source then e.g. RequirementsSource.DeferRefresh(); before starting your sort then refreshing afterwards so the ItemsPanel is only hit with one update.

Comment: @Cadogi The refresh doesn't happen until I explicitly call it right now.

Comment: sorry I assumed there would be a notification in IPropertyRequirement which would have forced an update. The only other thing worth noting is that your XAML doesn't produce the 'FluidMoveBehavior' object in the visual tree (in my Blend anyway) - not sure if that may be a sign the ItemsTemplate is interfering with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `RequirementsSource.Refresh();` line from your code.

Since you are using livesorting, animations starts when Requirement.Rank changes (PropertyChanged event is fired). But when you call refresh, it raises CollectionChanged with Reset argument and it forces the listbox to refresh.

**EDIT:**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel 
{
    ObservableCollection<Requirement> requirements;
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        requirements = new ObservableCollection<Requirement>(Enumerable
            .Range(0, 10)
            .Select(i => new Requirement {Rank = 10 - i, Name = "Item " + i}));

        RequirementsSource = new ListCollectionView(requirements);
        var live = (ICollectionViewLiveShaping)RequirementsSource;
        live.IsLiveSorting = true;
        live.IsLiveFiltering = true;
        live.LiveSortingProperties.Add("Rank");
        RequirementsSource.SortDescriptions.Add(
            new SortDescription("Rank", ListSortDirection.Ascending)
        );
        ReorderCommand = new DelegateCommand(Reorder);
    }

    public ListCollectionView RequirementsSource { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand ReorderCommand { get; private set; }

    private void Reorder()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < requirements.Count - 1; i += 2)
        {
            var temp = requirements[i].Rank;
            requirements[i].Rank = requirements[i + 1].Rank;
            requirements[i + 1].Rank = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Requirement : BindableBase
{
    private double _rank;

    public double Rank
    {
        get { return _rank; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _rank, value); }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This ended up being the correct answer (the key part being that refresh was firing the Reset argument). In order to do this, I needed to pull the `PropertyRequirementViewModel`s I had created that had `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented for the `Rank` property in the `SwapRanks` method rather than the actual object itself. I also wrapped them in `DeferRefresh` as Cadogi suggested.

Comment: I'm not sure why you use DeferRefresh and then you call PropertyChanged from SwapRank. I have added sample code that worked for me just fine

Comment: now that the propertychanged event fires when the Rank property changes for those object, it is firing twice: once when I set first, and once when I set second. I added DeferRefresh so that this will only cause one refresh. I removed the explicit refresh call from the method.

Comment: I believe that ItemsControl databound to ListCollectionView with LiveShaping is already optimized and DefferRefresh in not necessary. Simply said, the ItemsControl is not refreshed each time the PropertyChanged is called in a loop